# Remove duplicates rows based on a column MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I'm trying to delete all rows having the same column value in MySQL, but taking only the last row. the equivalent in Python would be:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='column_content', keep="last")
```

any idea?

I've tried:

```
sqlStatement = '''
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
WHERE t1.column_content = t2.column_content
  AND t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
'''
test = pd.read_sql(sql, con=connectionInstance)
```

Comment: "...but taking only the last row" -- there's no such thing as the last row in relational databases. You'll need to define a specific ordering criteria for it. Which one is it?

Comment: How find the latest row ? Id or timestamp or .... ?

Comment: just taking one from the similar ones. It doesn't have to be the last or first. It could be any

Comment: *It could be any* It could NOT. You MUST specify some order applying which each record is unique.

Comment: 'timestamp' is a unique ID in my table

Comment: i've edited my question

Comment: *I've tried:* You SELECT the records. In subj and in the text you tell that you want to REMOVE (DELETE) them. These words contradicts each other. Edit. Formulate your goal more scrupulously.

Comment: i've done SELECT to check first before deleting data from my database. And this sql query doesn't seem to select the rows i want to delete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM source_table t1
JOIN source_table t2
WHERE t1.some_column = t2.some_column
  AND t1.id < t2.id
/* Alternatively AND t1.datetime_field < t2.datetime_field */
```